# Concatenação Javascript com PHP

Tags: php, javascript, concatenação-de-string

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var max_fields1      = 6;  
  var wrapper1         = $("#container1");
  var add_button1      = $("#add_tipo_telha");

  var x = 0;

  $(add_button1).click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      if(x < max_fields1){

          $(wrapper1).append(
            '<div id="tipo_telha_div_'+ x +'" class="input-group margin">'+
            '<div id="tipo_telha_nome'+ x +'"></div>'+
              '<div class="input-group-btn">'+
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" id="delete" href="#">Remover</button>'+
              '</div>'+
              '&emsp;<select name="cob_tipoTelha'+ x +'" id="cob_tipoTelha'+ x +'" style = "margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 25px" required font-size: 18px onchange="exibir_ocultar_telha(this, '+ x +')">'+
                      '<option value="">Selecione</option>'+
                      '<option value="1"'+'<?=($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoTermoAcu"] == "Sim") ? "selected=selected" : "";?>'+'>Telha Termoacústica</option>'+
                      '<option value="2"'+'<?=($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoCeram"] == "Sim") ? "selected=selected" : "";?>'+'>Telha Cerâmica</option>'+
                      '<option value="3"'+'<?=($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoFibrocAmiant"] == "Sim") ? "selected=selected" : "";?>'+'>Telha de Fibrocimento (com amianto)</option>'+
                      '<option value="4"'+'<?=($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoFibroc"] == "Sim") ? "selected=selected" : "";?>'+'>Telha de Fibrocimento (sem amianto)</option>'+
                      '<option value="5"'+'<?=($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoZinco"] == "Sim") ? "selected=selected" : "";?>'+'>Telha de Zinco</option>'+
                      '<option value="6"'+'<?=($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoOutros"] == "Sim") ? "selected=selected" : "";?>'+'>Outros</option>'+
                  '</select>'+
                  '<div id="telha_outros'+ x +'" style=" display: none; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-left: 25px "><input id="outros_telha'+ x +'" type="text"  placeholder="Especifique" name= "telha_outros'+ x +'"/></div>'+
                  // '<input type="text" style= "margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'+ x +'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'+  +'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>'+
                  <?php
                  $x = 0;

                     if($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoTermoAcu"] == "Sim"){
                       echo('<input type="text" style= "margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" value="'.$dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoTermoAcuQtd"].'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>');
                     }
                     elseif($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoCeram"] == "Sim"){
                       echo('<input type="text" style= "margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" value="'.$dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoCeramQtd"].'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>');
                     }
                     elseif($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoFibrocAmiant"] == "Sim"){
                       echo('<input type="text" style= "margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" value="'.$dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoFibrocAmiantQtd"].'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>');
                     }
                     elseif($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoFibroc"] == "Sim"){
                       echo('<input type="text" style= "margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" value="'.$dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoFibrocQtd"].'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>');
                      }
                      elseif($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoZinco"] == "Sim"){
                        echo('<input type="text" style= "margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" value="'.$dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoZincoQtd"].'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>');
                      }
                      elseif($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoOutros"] == "Sim"){
                        echo('<input type="text" style= "margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" value="'.$dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoOutrosQtd"].'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>');
                      }
                      else{
                        echo('<input type="text" style="margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" placeholder="Quantidade" required /> m<sup>2</sup>');
                    }
                    $x++;
                  ?>

              '</div>'); //add input box
                x++;
      }
      else{alert('Número de tipo de telhas máximo atingido!');}

  });
```

e dá o erro

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

Poderiam me ajudar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você precisa incluir todos em todos os `echo`, aspas simples escapada, que será a continuação da concatenação do JavaScript, além do que precisa também concatenar a última linha do append (`'</div>'`):

Em todos os echos ficaria, assim:

```
echo('\'<input type="text" ... m<sup>2</sup>\'');
      ↑↑                                    ↑↑
```

E na última linha, acrescentar um `+`:

```
+'</div>');
↑
```

Comment: Entendi, obrigada

Answer (score 0):

Nesta parte do seu código

```
<?php
    $x = 0;

    if($dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoTermoAcu"] == "Sim"){
      echo('<input type="text" style= "margin-left: 25px" name= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" id= "cob_tipoTelha_qtd'.$x.'" value="'.$dados_ficha_tecnica["cob_tipoTermoAcuQtd"].'" placeholder="Quantidade" required/> m<sup>2</sup>');
    }
     ...            
 ?>
```

você esta imprimindo `<input type=...` dentro do seu javascript. Aparentemente nessa parte você não esta concatenando e nem é string.

acho que se você colocar `'` antes de `<?php`, e depois de `?>` colocar `'+` deve funcionar